# GmailApp.sendEmail cannot send email containing the word "calf" through google apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I'm trying to send an email that contains an auto-fill link for a google form, but the email doesn't send. One of the variables that make up the auto-link includes the word "calf" in it. When I changed the variable to another string, it would send the email. Then when I changed a different variable to "calf" or a string containing "calf" it stopped sending again. Is the word itself a problem or is it something else?

```
  var emailAddress = email;
  var text = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdFDFGDFVDGGjdfgdfgdx8P4DOw/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.745541291="+room+"&entry.1045781291="+rr+"&entry.1065046570=4&entry.1166974658="+hr+"&entry.839337160="+spO2+"&entry.103735076=&entry.515842896="+e1Name+"&entry.631828469="+e1Reps+"&entry.1814472044="+e2Name+"&entry.905508655="+e2Reps+"&entry.1234390406="+isVol+"&entry.197252120="+education+"&entry.1748983288="+notes;
  var message = 'Dear ' + patientName + '\n\n' + "Thank you for submitting.\n\nHere is an autofill link: " + text; 
  var subject = 'Submission Confirmation';
  GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
```

Comment: Is there any error message or other output?

Comment: No error messages occur. The script will create a word document and add the variables to a spreadsheet with no error. All code under the SendEmail function is ran successfully.

Comment: If I run the script with:
var message = "calf";
It will not send the email. However, if I use "test" or any other string, I have no issues

Comment: Whoa.... I just found all of the emails that contain "calf", no matter where in the string, in my junk email. My entire message has been considered junk only because it contained "calf". Now I'm trying to fix that

Answer (score -1):

Turns out, any email I sent that contained the letters "calf" would automatically be sent to my junk mail. This issue occurs on two separate emails, both which are hosted by outlook. I went into the settings of outlook and made the sending email "safe". This is an odd situation, but the emails that contain "calf" are now being displayed in the primary inbox.

Answer (score -3):

I think that one of the querystring variables probably accidentally closes your string.

Consider building the querystring differently, for example:

```
const baseUrl = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdFDFGDFVDGGjdfgdfgdx8P4DOw/viewform"
let var1 = 'def';
const qsParams = {
    prop1: 'val1',
    prop2: 'val2',
    prop3: `abc${var1}`,
}

const querystring = Object.entries(qsParams)
    .map(([key, value]) => `${key}=${value}`)
    .join('&');

const url = `${baseUrl}?${querystring}`

console.log(url);
```

Comment: @Herohtar, if one of the vars in the querystring accidentally closes the quotes, it could crash the script earlier.

Comment: @Herohtar, re: the qs "bug" that I found, you are correct that the one I highlighted was not actually a problem. I've edited my answer to remove it.

Comment: The contents of the variables can not "close the quotes" and would not cause the script to crash like that.

Comment: If I directly comment out the variable that contains "calf" or change that variable to a different string, the email will send. Also if I comment out all of the message variable and leave only "calf" It still will not send. However, any other string will

Comment: @JimmyLeeSpann, This still seems like a sql injection type problem to me. Does that variable contain any puncutation? If it does, you may need to urlencode it or something.

Comment: Turns out, any message that contains the word "calf" gets sent to my junk inbox. Even if those four letters have other letters to right or left of it. I'm trying to find a fix to the problem. I think I found a work around in the outlook settings but it's not ideal

Comment: The answer contains several elements that aren't supported by default by Google Apps Script like an arrow function.